# Google Sheets: getting a sheet by its index

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get a sheet using a calculated index. I am having a problem but am unsure whether it's a problem converting a float to an integer or if there is a syntax error. What am I getting wrong?

```
function copySheetValues()
{

  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //get the source sheet data
  var sourceDataRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var sourceSheetValues = sourceDataRange.getValues();
  var sourceRows = sourceDataRange.getNumRows();
  var sourceColumns = sourceDataRange.getNumColumns();


  // get the source sheet index and set the next sheet index
  var sourcesheetIndex = sourceSheet.getIndex();
  var destinationsheetIndex = Math.round(sourcesheetIndex + 1);

  // get the next sheet
  var destinationSheet = spread.getSheets()[destinationsheetIndex]

  //destination.insertSheet(sourcename, 0);
  destinationSheet.getDataRange().offset(0, 0, sourceRows, sourceColumns).setValues(sourceSheetValues);

}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Enter it into the [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)  If for some reason it's not considered a bug, it's still a real problem.  The returned array of sheets is unusable if a dynamic index number can't be used to get specific sheet.

Comment: ... and you missed the ; at the end of var destinationSheet = spread.getSheets()[destinationsheetIndex]

Comment: I just tried the code without the semi-colon, and it doesn't seem to make any different.  But, the weird thing is, that the code seems to be getting the sheet object now.  I was debugging that code for quite a long time earlier today, and it was NOT getting the sheet object, and now it is, semi-colon or not.

Comment: I just did some more tests with hard coding the index number, and using an index number that is a variable.  When the index number is hard coded, the code works.  So, it's definitely some kind of bug with using a variable for the index in the sheets array.

Answer (score 3):

As `getIndex()` is 1 based and `getSheets()` is 0 based you might try:

```
var destinationSheet = spread.getSheets()[sourceSheet.getIndex()];
```

go figure

Caveat: getIndex() returns the sheets position within the spreadsheet where getSheets() has to do with the order in which the sheets were added and the two may not correspond if the spreadsheet has been rearranged after the sheets were added.

To insure that the destination sheet is the sheet located just after the source sheet:

```
// get the source sheet index and set the next sheet index
  var destinationsheetIndex = sourceSheet.getIndex() + 1;

// get the next sheet
  var sheets = spread.getSheets();
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    if(sheets[i].getIndex() == destinationsheetIndex ) {
      var destinationSheet = sheets[i];
      break;
      };
    };
```